# Automatically logout user when session expires in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, session

Is there a way to logout the user as soon as the session expires in Laravel? I know that maybe the easiest alternative to this is to let the logout happen when a request is sent after the session has expired, and in fact that's how I was handling it in my website, but because of some issues with frontend, I no longer can do that. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to schedule a simple check call from FE and check status.

Comment: What if someone closes the browser, where do you get the request from for that...

Comment: Please Add Some Code which you have tried before.

Comment: Ca't you just set the lifetime to x seconds and let laravel handle this and you would need to handle 403 status code (assuming you have done this) in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel handles this and provides a config file 'session.php'  for you to configure the options as per your needs.

An excerpt from the forementioned file

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 43200,

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```